# Responsive design not working on iPhone after deployment

Tags: html, css, iphone, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have successfully tested the responsive design of my website on an iPhone **locally** but when I **deploy** it the responsive design :

- works when resizing my browser's size on my desktop
- do not work on my iphone

When I say *it works* I mean I can see it toggles the Bootstrap navigation bar for small devices, uses my custom css media queries, etc.

I have these meta in my html :

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

The answers I have come across mention the meta tag but it is already present on my site (I used the HTML5 Boilerplate starter). Any other ideas ?

Comment: you say that you tested your design on an iPhone locally -- can you clarify what you mean by that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the issue... Not at all related to my code but to the redirection from my domain name to my hosted page. My provider was using a html wrapper that basically obliterated my HTML tags (and consequently my `<meta>` tags). What I did was just looking at the HTML and figuring something weird was happenning... I stopped using their odd web redirection and started configuring my DNS right. Everything is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could look for are css media queries which might specifically target iPhones or smartphones and stop them displaying a responsive behaviour, while leaving desktop browsers unutouched.

For example comment out or re-inspect any css media queries that target (min-device-width : x) or (max-device-width: y)

Alternatively, post a URL so we can inspect the css

Good luck

Comment: Thank you for your help :). Had to post this on SO to realize what was the real issue (see my answer above).